# Test instrumentation process crashed. After click action app should restarted but with espresso is crashed

Tags: automation, android-espresso

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. I just create a simple test case (Just click on the button)
2. After clicking on this button, the app should be restarted (Hard Restart) (Expected Result)
3. Testcase will fail and I get this error (Actual Result)

**(Test instrumentation process crashed. Check tests.SplashActivityTest#splashActivityTest.txt for details)**

The data on file mentioned before :

**INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0**

Prerequisites:

```
`android {
defaultConfig {
...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData:'true'

} }
...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
    }
    .....
    dependencies {
     // Espresso Dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.1-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.0-beta01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.jakewharton.espresso:okhttp3-idling-resource:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.schibsted.spain:barista:3.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
    } 

    //   orchestrator
    androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.4.1'
    }`
```

I try with **API 31** and **33** with Emulator and real devices too

Can anyone here help me with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have log from Logcat ?
Try to increase the orchestrator version to 1.4.2 and before that try to start your test with API 29.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me, discussion and solution available in the below link.

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/17266#issuecomment-1195073647

- adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server
- adb uninstall io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test
- After that launch Appium and rerun your script